# PHP and FPDF - sprintf not working with data in certain combinations

Tags: php, fpdf, printf

I'm having a problem with the following code. I want to use the content (taken from some Community Builder fields) to print to labels for envelopes.

The first line of the label will contain a subscriber's Title, First Name and Surname, and this works fine. I get a PDF with exactly the required info.

The second line is where things start to go pear-shaped. As soon as I try to include $faculty in Line 2 instead of the empty string I've got there in the code below, the PDF produced downloads as 0 bytes and Acrobat says it's not a supported file type.

Weird thing is that I can print $faculty onto the label if I don't also include the first line.

The code I'm working with previously printed the same data to a CSV. I just need it to go to PDF instead.

Anyone know why this is happening and can point me in the right direction? There's commas and stuff in many of the fields I'm using but that wouldn't make any difference would it?

Cheers!

Note for clarity: This code WORKS. What DOESN'T work is when I replace the $lineTwo assignment below with '$lineTwo = sprintf("%s",$faculty);'. Or '$lineTwo = "$faculty");".

```
foreach($activeSubscribers as $subscriber) {
$title = $subscriber->$fields[0][1];
$firstname = $subscriber->$fields[1][1];
$surname = $subscriber->$fields[2][1];
$faculty = $subscriber->$fields[3][1];          
$institution = $subscriber->$fields[4][1];  
$address1 = $subscriber->$fields[5][1]; 
$address2 = $subscriber->$fields[6][1]; 
$suburb = $subscriber->$fields[7][1]; 
$state = $subscriber->$fields[8][1];        
$postcode = $subscriber->$fields[9][1]; 
$country = $subscriber->$fields[10][1]; 

$lineOne = sprintf("%s %s %s",$title, $firstname, $surname);

$lineTwo = "";              // should have faculty and institution
$lineThree = sprintf("%s",$suburb); // should have address line 1 
$lineFour = "";             // should have address line 2
$lineFive = "";             // should have suburb, state, postcode
$lineSix = "";              // should have country
```

Comment: wonderful! Now, I also working with fpdf. :). So, you want to create pdf format.. right? If right, let me know your code detail. The above code is not completed. It's difficult to help. Here my created fpdf sample http://www.sendspace.com/file/mng1z8

Comment: Thanks! Full copy of the file is in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6068106

Comment: I'm using one of the example scripts they provide, and building on it. The example script is this one: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php

Comment: Their example prints the same string to the address label 20 times. I'm using the code in my gist to get data from Community Builder in Joomla and put that on the labels instead.

Comment: So, you mean, Line one is printed with pdf format? When you add line two, it's not supported format come out?

Comment: Line one is printed (with title, firstname and surname). if I add line three as above (with suburb) this causes the PDF to be 0 bytes.

Comment: If I remove line one, line three prints fine. But they won't both print.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add this line

```
$text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", $lineOne, $lineTwo, $lineThree, $lineFour);
$pdf->Add_Label($text);
```

If you don't want to use sprintf(), you can print line by line like that

```
$pdf->Add_Label($lineone);
$pdf->Add_Label($linetwo);
```

Try this option

```
$pdf->Write(0.2,$lineone);
$pdf->Write(0.2,$linetwo);
```

Comment: $text = sprintf("%s\n%s", $lineOne,  $lineThree); Only print in lineone and linethree. Don't make blank string value in lineone and linetwo. Put same value to these two.

Comment: Yes, that's what causes the problem. When I include both lineOne and lineThree together like that.